# can an assignment operator be overloaded to assign a string literal to a user definded string type?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

This first section is a web example

Assignment:

You can assign a C++ string, a C string, or a C string literal to a C++ string.

Examples:

```
string s1 = "original string";
string s2 = "new string";
char s3[20] = "another string";

s1 = s2;//s1 changed to "new string"
s1 = s3;//s1 changed to "another string"
s1 = "yet another string";
   //s1 changed to "yet another string"
   //Once again, this works because.
   //operator overloading.
```

This is technically my question below

```
class my_string{
public:
.
.
my_string& operator=(const my_string&);
.
.
.
};
```

if this is the only assignment
operator overload allowed then how
does `s1` get the value of `"yet another string"` in the above example?

Comment: 1. Your [tag:c] tag is wrong, 2. Your `string` objects and the string literals are not both "*strings*", in the context of [tag:c++] you should be careful to distinguish between these.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to allow the assignment, or are you saying that the assignment is allowed and asking why?

Comment: Does your class have any constructors that convert from another string type to `my_string`?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The example above uses `std::string`, not `my_string`.

Comment: I pulled an example from the internet that involved std::string objects being assigned by literal strings. Then I showed what the operator overload looks like in my class. I can't figure out why the operator overload function is only allowed to accept as an argument a member of the same class, but std::string is able to overload it differently.

Comment: Why are u creating your own string class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, that's because it is not the only assignment operator,  there are other overloaded definitions. These are for C++98, there are others for C++11.

```
string& operator= (const string& str);
string& operator= (const char* s);
string& operator= (char c);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/

`s1 = "yet another string";` uses the second operator in the list, while `s1 = s2;` uses the first.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, we must provide a overloaded assignment operator like this:

```
string& operator= (const char* s);
```

but I tested it. It's OK without it.

```
int main()
{
    mystring s = "assss";
    cout << s << endl;
    s = "aaaaaaaaa";
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

maybe the compiler will call this one:`mystring(const char * st);`
then create a temporary object, the assign it to s1.